# node-xmpp-server vs node-xmpp-client

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, node-xmpp

I'm in the process creating sample chat app that need to works both in mobile and web with node application and **ejabbered server using xmpp protocol**.using **xmpp** protocol for the **node-ejabbered** connection I am facing confusion with the several modules **node-xmpp-client** and **node-xmpp-server**. I am new to this please anyone suggest which is to be used among 2 and correct me if i am wrong.

And what is the role of node-xmpp module if there is already 2 modules node-xmpp-client and node-xmpp-server.

please clear my confusion, I can't get clear thought with descriptions given in the other sites

Thanks

Comment: this should be asked on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: please can anyone share an idea about the connection between node-xmpp-client to ejabbered server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both **node-xmpp-client** and **node-xmpp-server** are deprecated and the whole **node-xmpp** family as well.

There is a separate https://github.com/xmppjs/xmpp.js which is a replacement for them.

This library is good for the following things:

- Node.js
- Web browser
- Native Script
- React Native

So you can use this lib if you want to interract from all above environments with your Ejabberd server.

Also, if we are talking about Web only - there is a good Web browser lib: http://strophe.im/strophejs/

Also, if we are talking about native mobile, there are 2 XMPP libs for native iOS & Android:

- https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework for iOS native  apps
- https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack for Android native apps

=====

You do not need to use 'node-xmpp-server' at all. You already have an XMPP server (Ejabberd). You just need to interact with it from your mobile & web apps using above libs.

If you are going to use some Native Script / Reeact Native for mobile apps development then you can use a single lib **xmpp.js** on both mobile and web apps. If you are going to use native iOS/Android SDK - then you need to use XMPPFramework & Smack on mobile and Strophe.js (or xmpp.js) on web.

Comment: You do not need to use 'node-xmpp-server' at all. You already have an XMPP server (Ejabberd). You just need to interact with it from your mobile & web apps.

Comment: Updated my answer with more info